# Отслеживание нажатия на кнопку UI

Tags: unity3d, ui

Всем привет! Нужно отследить условие нажатия на конкретные элементы UI (спрайты), а после запустить процессы Command. На сцене спрайты генерируются из нескольких префабов при старте. Читал, смотрел, искал, думал как сделать. В итоге есть 2 скрипта. Первый ставлю на префабы. Второй использую для реализации событий.

Вопрос - что я делаю не так? Дебаг работает, сообщения приходят, но второй скрипт кнопку не видит и метод OnPointerEnter не запускает.

'''

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MouseOverUI : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Мышь зашла на меня" + name);
    }
}
```

'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera mainCam;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Material oldMaterial;

    [SerializeField] private CommandManager commandManager;
    [SerializeField] private MouseOverUI mouseOverUI;

    private MouseOverUI ClickDetector;

    public List<Material> list = new List<Material>();


    void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main;

        ClickDetector = mouseOverUI.GetComponent<MouseOverUI>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (ClickDetector.OnPointerEnter())
        {
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
                {

                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                    {
                        Material newMaterial = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

                        list.Add(newMaterial);

                        GameObject obj = hit.collider.gameObject;

                        commandManager.ExecuteCommand(new ChangeMatCommand(oldMaterial, newMaterial, obj));
                    }
                }

                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

`if (ClickDetector.OnPointerEnter())`? Это не `bool`, a `void` функция, они ничего не возвращет.

```
public class MouseOverUI : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {

    public bool IsOver { get; private set; }

    public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData) {
        IsOver = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData) {
        IsOver = false;
    }
}
...
if (ClickDetector.IsOver) { }
```